# using a SUM IF formula in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to sum "Order Qty" from a table in my Access database where "Material group name" equals "Generic Rx" through a Sum if formula

I am using:

```
Gen Ordered: SUM(IIF([Material group Name]=(Generic Rx).[Order Qty],0)
```

but I am getting an invalid syntax error at the Generic Rx expression

"Generic Rx" is value within the "Material group name" column

what is the best way to go about this? Thanks

Comment: What is "Generic Rx"? A table an object, something else?

Comment: While I don't use IIF's frequently, I think you need a "False part".  Something like `IIF([Material group Name]=(Generic Rx).[Order Qty],1,0)` Though it still seems like an odd comparison, can you explain each part of `[Material group Name]=(Generic Rx).[Order Qty]` in greater detail?

Comment: Is "Generic Rx" a column in your table? If so, the right way to write this is: `Sum(IIF([Material group Name] = [Generic Rx], [Order Qty], 0))`

Comment: There's quite a few issues with your expression. As you mention, "Generic Rx" is the value but you have it set up as if it was a table looking for [Order Qty] field. You must equate Material Group Name to the string value. Also, the IIF() requires three arguments (condition,if true, if false) which you only have two arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SUM(IIF([Material group Name]=(Generic Rx).[Order Qty],0)
                              |           |              |
                              1           2              3
```

1. Use quotes instead of parentheses to delimit literal text values.
2. Use commas between `IIf` arguments.
3. Every open parenthesis must be balanced by a close parenthesis.

This should be closer ...

```
SUM(IIF([Material group Name]="Generic Rx",[Order Qty],0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear as you don't explain us what the different elements are. If we assume that `Generic Rx` is a query parameter and `Order Qty` is a table column then your expression must be

```
Gen Ordered:     Sum( IIF([Material group Name] = [Generic Rx], [Order Qty],    0) )
'                                                                  |            |
'Name of                  |<-------------- condition ------->|   true-part  false part
'result column
'                     IIF( <condition>, <result if true>, <result if false>)
```

Meaning: If `Material group Name` equals `Generic Rx` Then the result will be `Order Qty` else it will be `0`.

Comment: I.e. it is a query parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that either until HansUp's post, I think that "." that should have been a "," is what made it really confusing.

Comment: Yeah, first I thought that `Generic Rx` was a table and `Order Qty` a column within this table. In that case the syntax would have been `[Generic Rx].[Order Qty]`.